# AdsByGoogle shows in App

Tags: javascript, ionic2, google-ads-api

I've pulled json data from my Wordpress website to my ionic app.
One of the post contains google ads inside the post. 
When viewed this post in App the following code is shown:-

```
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
```

How to handle this?

Comment: Can you clarify how you are pulling the data? You are using the API, I presume?

Comment: Yes. I've pulled the data using JSON-API.

Comment: As you know, that's JavaScript code, probably created by a WP plugin. In what way does it show up? Is it inside `<script>` tags? Is there regular content, too?

Comment: Well in the Wordpress Dashboard the 
<script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</script>
tag was inserted in the post but in the website it results to google ads but in the app side (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({}); this is displayed.

Comment: How are you viewing the post in the app? Can you show some code?

Comment: I'm working on Ionic so the below code is used to display the post content.

 <div [innerHTML]="post.content"></div>

Comment: Hmm, not sure why the contents of the `<script>` tag are showing up as plain text then. You may have to filter it out, but I don't know Ionic & how to do that